# {message: "Unsupported operand types", exception: "Error",…} in F12 /Network

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I don't know why i am getting this error on this line of code:  `$gross = $gross + $grosstotal;`
I want to get sum of all $grosstotal in loop and send it to DB. I am getting this error only after pressing f12 and pressing "Network" tab in web browser.
This is full code of my controller witch generates error:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\DynamicField;
use Validator;
use App\Proform; 


class DynamicFieldController extends Controller
{
    function index()
    {
     return view('proforms.create');
    }

    function insert(Request $request)
    {

        

     if($request->ajax())
     {
      $rules = array(
       'name.*'  => 'required',
       'PKWIU.*'  => 'required',
       'quantity.*'  => 'required',
       'unit.*'  => 'required',
       'netunit.*'  => 'required',
       'nettotal.*'  => 'required',
       'VATrate.*'  => 'required',
       'grossunit.*'  => 'required',
       'grosstotal.*'  => 'required',
       'proform_id.*'  => 'required',
      );
      $error = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
      if($error->fails())
      {
       return response()->json([
        'error'  => $error->errors()->all()
       ]);
      }
      $autonumber = DB::table("proforms as proforms")
      ->select(DB::raw('MAX(id) as id'))  
      ->get();     
      
      $number = $autonumber[0]->id;

      $autonumber2 = DB::table("dynamic_fields as dynamic_fields")
      ->select(DB::raw('MAX(id) as id'))  
      ->get();
  
      
      $autonumber2[0]->id++;
      $number2 = $autonumber2[0]->id;
    

      $name = $request->name;
      $PKWIU = $request->PKWIU;
      $quantity = $request->quantity;
      $unit = $request->unit;
      $netunit = $request->netunit;
      $nettotal = $request->nettotal;
      $VATrate = $request->VATrate;
      $grossunit = $request->grossunit;
      $grosstotal = $request->grosstotal;
      for($count = 0; $count < count($name); $count++)
      {
      
       $data = array(
        'proform_id' => $number, 
        'id_pozycji' => $number2++,  
        'name' => $name[$count],
        'PKWIU'  => $PKWIU[$count],
        'quantity' => $quantity[$count],
        'unit'  => $unit[$count],
        'netunit' => $netunit[$count],
        'nettotal'  => $nettotal[$count],
        'VATrate' => $VATrate[$count],
        'grossunit'  => $grossunit[$count],
        'grosstotal' => $grosstotal[$count],

       );
       $gross = $gross + $grosstotal;
       $net = $net + $nettotal; 

       $insert_data[] = $data; 
      }
     $affected = DB::table('proforms')
      ->where('id', $number)
      ->update(['gross' => $gross]);

      $affected2 = DB::table('proforms')
      ->where('id', $number)
      ->update(['net' => $net]);  
      DynamicField::insert($insert_data);
     
      return response()->json([
       'success'  => 'Data Added successfully.'
      ]);
     }
    }
}
```

This is view with Ajax for it

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Laravel 5.8 - DataTables Server Side Processing using Ajax</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>




 <div id="top" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 20px;">


 @extends('layouts.app')


@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Dodaj nową proformę</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('proforms.index') }}">Wstecz</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @if(session()->has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session()->get('message') }}
    </div>
    @endif

    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif


    <form action="{{ route('proforms.store') }}" method="POST">
        @csrf


         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Data wystawienia:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="proformdate"  class="form-control" placeholder="Data wystawienia">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Kontrahent:</strong>
                                        <br>
                    <select class="form-controll" name="user_id">
                            @foreach($users as $user)
                            <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->showname}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                    </select>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Waluta:</strong>
                                        <br>
                    <select class="form-controll" name="currency_id">
                            @foreach($currencys as $currency)
                            <option value="{{$currency->id}}">{{$currency->currency}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                    </select>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Forma płatności:</strong>
                                        <br>
                    <select class="form-controll" name="form_id">
                            @foreach($forms as $form)
                            <option value="{{$form->id}}">{{$form->form}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                    </select>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Data sprzedaży:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="selldate" class="form-control" placeholder="Kategoria">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Termin płatności:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="paymentdate"  class="form-control" placeholder="Termin płatności">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Forma płatności:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="paymentmethod" class="form-control" placeholder="Forma płatności">
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Miejsce wystawienia:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control" placeholder="Forma płatności">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Status:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="status" class="form-control" placeholder="Status">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Uwagi:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="comments" class="form-control" placeholder="Uwagi">
                </div>
            </div>
 
           



            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
            <h5>Najpierw zapisz proformę, aby dodać do niej pozycje</h5>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Zapisz</button>
            </div>
        </div>


    </form>

    @if(session()->has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session()->get('message') }}
    </div>
@endif



</div>
<div class="pull-left" style="margin: 15px;">
                
                <h3>Pozycje proformy</h3>
</div>

 

   
   
   <div class="table-responsive">
                <form method="post" id="dynamic_form">
                 <span id="result"></span>
                 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="user_table">
               <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="10%">Nazwa towaru lub usługi</th>
                    <th width="10%">PKWiU</th>
                    <th width="10%">Ilość</th>
                    <th width="10%">Jednostka</th>
                    <th width="10%">Cena netto</th>
                    <th width="10%">Netto razem</th>
                    <th width="10%">Stawka VAT</th>
                    <th width="10%">Brutto jednostka</th>
                    <th width="10%">Brutto razem</th>
                    <th width="10%">Action</th>
                </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>

               </tbody>
               <tfoot>
                <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>
                  @csrf
                  <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
                 </td>
                </tr>
               </tfoot>
           </table>
                </form>
                @endsection   
   </div>
  
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 var count = 1;

 dynamic_field(count);

 function dynamic_field(number)
 {
  html = '<tr>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="PKWIU[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="unit[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="netunit[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="nettotal[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="VATrate[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="grossunit[]" class="form-control" /></td>';        
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="grosstotal[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
        if(number > 1)
        {
            html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" id="" class="btn btn-danger remove">Remove</button></td></tr>';
            $('tbody').append(html);
        }
        else
        {   
            html += '<td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add</button></td></tr>';
            $('tbody').html(html);
        }
 }

 $(document).on('click', '#add', function(){
  count++;
  dynamic_field(count);
 });

 $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
  count--;
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
 });

 $('#dynamic_form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:'{{ route("dynamic-field.insert") }}',
            method:'post',
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            dataType:'json',
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#save').attr('disabled','disabled');
            },
            success:function(data)
            {
                if(data.error)
                {
                    var error_html = '';
                    for(var count = 0; count < data.error.length; count++)
                    {
                        error_html += '<p>'+data.error[count]+'</p>';
                    }
                    $('#result').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+error_html+'</div>');
                }
                else
                {
                    dynamic_field(1);
                    $('#result').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data.success+'</div>');
                }
                $('#save').attr('disabled', false);
            }
        })
 });

});
</script>
```

Comment: What's the value of both variables and why are you sum it inside the for loop?

Comment: Your `$gross` variable is never defined. You should define it as 0. Also, you cannot use `+` to concatenate string in php. If it's what you are trying to do, you need to use  `.`

Comment: I defined them $gross and $net as 0 , $gross=0; but have got same error.

Comment: it is not string. it is integer. i want to get sum of all values of grosstotal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not accessing the array elements.
All your request variables are arrays:

```
 $gross = $gross + $grosstotal;
 $net = $net + $nettotal;
```

You will need to call the addition with the indexed variable: `$grossunit[$count]` etc. or access it via your data array in the loop: `$data['grossunit']`.

You also never initialize `$gross` and `$net` variable. You will need to set them = 0 outside the loop otherwise the `+=` operand won't work.